# Raise a number to a power with new formula using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

after being up for the whole night and giving up, I decided to ask for some help on here.
Following is giving me a headache.
I need to write a recursive method which raises a number to a power using this formula:
a^n = a^(n%2) * a^(n/2) * a^(n/2) | n > 1

I just can't get my hand behind it, as how to do it with only two parameters.

```
public class raise {
         public int recursiveRaiseModulo(int base, int power) {
       }
}
```

I could really use some help, so thank you in advance!

As I don't want it to look like I haven't tried anything, this is what I've come up with. Well it's quite honestly garbage.

```
public static void recursiveRaiseModulo(int base, int power, int powerCounter) {
        int solution = (int) Math.pow(base, (powerCounter % 2)) * (int) Math.pow(base, (powerCounter / 2)) * (int) Math.pow(base, (powerCounter / 2));
        if (power == 0 && powerCounter == 2) {
            System.out.println("2. Recursive - Solution: 1");
        } else if (powerCounter < power) {
            raise.recursiveRaiseModulo(base, power, powerCounter + 2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("2. Recursive - Solution: " + solution);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if it is a must to use recursion. If it is not, I think we can use `return (int) ((n % 2 == 0) ? Math.pow(a, n) : Math.pow(a, n + 1));` since a^(n%2) * a^(n/2) * a^(n/2) = a^( (n%2) + n).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need more than two arguments:

```
public int recursiveRaiseModulo(int base, int power) {
    if (power == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    int halfPower = recursiveRaiseModulo (base, power / 2);
    return (power % 2 == 1 ? base : 1) * halfPower * halfPower;
    //            a^(n % 2)            *  a^(n/2)  *  a^(n/2)
}
```

Note that `a^(n%2)` is equal to `a` when `n` is odd and equal to `1` when `n` is even.

Comment: If you did part 1, i.e. `(power % 2 == 1 ? base : 1)`, separately and assigned result to a variable, and you did it *before* the `if` statement, you could easily make the code handle `power = 0` too.

Comment: @Andreas the question did specify that `n > 1`. Anyway, I added an alternative that supports power of 0 too.

Comment: If that was truly so, then why did you write `if (power == 1)` in the first block and `if (power == 0)` in the second block, if `power > 1`? --- The `n > 1` *condition* is the condition for applying *that* formula. When `n = 1` or `n = 0`, different formulas must be applied, even if not explicitly listed in the question. You even implemented the `n = 1` formula in the first block and the `n = 0` formula in the second block.

Comment: @Andreas I took `n > 1` to mean that the method will never be called from outside with power <= 1, so I set the stopping condition at `power == 1`. Then I realized that the recursion would also work if I set the stopping condition at `power == 0`, so I suggested the second alternative.

Comment: Since the method can be called from *inside* with `power = 1` (and maybe even with `power = 0`), it can certainly be called from *outside* with that value, which means that `n > 1` is not a constraint on the *method*, but a constraint of the listed *formula*, i.e. for other values of `n`, a different formula is needed. The question is simply incomplete, in that is doesn't specify which formulas to use for other values of `n`.

Comment: @Andreas fine. I accept your argument. I removed my original suggestion.